# how to kill a process in java after completion of a job in java

Tags: java

I have a code similar to:

```
URL url = Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry("/resources/server.bat");
String fileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(url).toString();
String commandLine = "cmd.exe /c start " +fileURL;
Process process= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
```

How can I  kill the process as soon as the work is done  in java

Comment: Surely when the work is done the spawned application exits anyway?  What does server.bat do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`process.destroy()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29)

But it won't have control over the process started from `server.bat` those are separately started

Comment: Thank You that is what I am looking for..... server.bat is creating a file (for example)I want to kill the process as asoon as the file is created...is it possible?

Comment: Thank You
For my case untill unless the main application is terminated its not creating the new file...Please help regarding that

Comment: it shouldn't be the case. also if you can generate file from java it would be the best. how do you detect if file has generated ?

Comment: actually by this executable I am using some utility wich is creating another .exe.once it is generated I am launching it... but for some cases it is hanging the whole application. only if I terminate the application I can see the file to be generated in my file system

Comment: might be the issue in the executable. does this happen if you run it externally , not from java

Comment: may be you can open up a new post with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime.exec creates a Process which actually is a sub-shell on the target machine. This particular sub-shell could be killed or terminated using process.destroy(); method. But the particular subprocess may have spawned many other subprocesses for other external commands in the batch or shell script. If we kill the parent process, the child processes may not be killed and that may worsen the situation.

Comment: Thank You Amit
Can I use wait() notify() to check if the job (e.g. a new file creation )is completed for the particular .bat file

Comment: No you cannot use wait() - notify() here. Using Runtime calss you can only execute a system command or script. After you fire the Runtime.exec() the control of command or script is not in the scope of your JVM. It was a system command you fired and so it is being run by the OS. You only have control over the object of the Process class which can be used to collect the output of the commnad or provide input or to destroy the process. There is a waitFor() method which can be used to hold the current thread from terminating unless the subprocess owned by Process object terminates.

Comment: Thank You Amit.. I will try with this what else if I use Process Builder  and supply  the exacutable directly other that using runtime.exe()? actually for my case untill unless the application is terminated server.bat is not creating the new file...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must already know that, when you execute a Java program it runs on a JVM (Java Virtual Machine). Thus when you execute the “tasklist” command you’ll not be able to see your Java process name.

Fortunately when you have the JDK installed you can see all the java processes which are running on your machine by using the Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool. To use it just type the “jps” command:

As you can see the “jps” command gives you all the needed information like the PID and the java process name. So by using the java process name you are now able to kill the desired process.

Here you can find the magic command line:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %i in ('jps -m ^| find "JAVA_PROCESS_NAME"') do ( taskkill /F /PID %i )
```

This command will execute the “jps -m” command and get the PID of the java processes which contain the given “JAVA_PROCESS_NAME” and execute a “taskkill /F /PID” over. N.B.1: replace the “JAVA_PROCESS_NAME” by your own process name. N.B.2: For the bat files put a double % (%%i) instead of one.

For example, to kill the Eclipse program type this command:

```
C:\Users\YannickL>for /f "tokens=1" %i in ('jps -m ^| find "Eclipse"') do ( taskkil l /F /PID %i ) C:\Users\YannickL>(taskkill /F /PID 5076 ) SUCCESS: The process with PID 5076 has been terminated.
```